# c# Settngs "Button" to prompt for a default printer to use, save setting to ini file

Tags: c#, printing

I am looking to implement a settings button to prompt a user for a default printer to use and then save these settings to an ini file.

I am already using the ini file for other environmental settings and this is working fine (adding, reading, updating etc)

I just need to grab the user selection, save this choice and use this choice when the user prints.

Another requirement is that the selected printer, when a job is sent, it needs to be done silently. (ie nor prompting the standard windows print dialogue/printer selection)

Any ideas or pointers appreciated.

Cheers,
Courtney.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Any code to show? We're not here to write code for you. [mcve]. [ask]

Comment: I post some code examples when I start on this module, I was just after some hints if there was any built in libraries that I can use to use for the selection part etc. Keep you posted.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get a list of the installed printers using and adding them to a combobox :-

```
 foreach (string printer in PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters)
 printerCombo.Items.Add(printer);
```

Using the iniparser library I can now output the setting to an ini file from the selected combobox entry upon selection.

```
        var iniParser = new FileIniDataParser();
        IniData settings = new IniData();
```